# fastest way to search pandas dataframe that contains text and duplicate values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, search

I have a 10m row dataframe, like this:

```
rdata={'first': {0: 'john', 1: 'david', 2: 'daniel', 3: 'john'}, 'last': {0: 'smith', 1: 'jones', 2: 'bond', 3: 'smith'}, 'ph': {0: 123456, 1: 456789, 2: 12345, 3: 234567}, 'address': {0: 'AB12 3CB', 1: 'EF45 6GH', 2: 'IJ78 9KL', 3: 'AB32 3CD'}, 'email': {0: 'js@js.com', 1: 'dj@dj.com', 2: 'db@db.com', 3: 'js@js.com'}, 'id': {0: 12345678, 1: 90123456, 2: 78901234, 3: 98765432}}
df = pd.DataFrame(rdata)
```

I want to search based on first and last name, and extract the corresponding records.

I am using the following methods:

```
d=data.loc[(data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john')]
d=data[(data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john')]
d=data.iloc[np.where((data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john'))]
```

each of these methods are very similar in time to exectute (1.73s), but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to search for records.

I tried converting `df.to_numpy()[(df['last']=='smith') & (df['first']=='john')]` but do not see noticeable gains.

are there any other possibilities I might be missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) **could** be a bit faster on large datasets:

```
df.query('(last == "smith") & (first == "john")')
```

40 rows:

```
# query
1.45 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# loc
239 µs ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

40k rows:

```
# query
3.74 ms ± 318 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# loc
5.06 ms ± 597 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

It might depend on the exact dataset, so better try with yours

Comment: I can up with the same solution you did with a bit more coding and an image.   I can't post a picture from this location.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston I added the image for you ;)

Comment: @ScottBoston and @mozway, thanks for the `query` suggestion. I too found the paradox you mentioned, and query is 35% faster

Comment: @frank I don't think of it as a paradox. :)  I believe I once saw and explanation for this performance increase by query.  I will see if I can find it again.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an interesting observation, `pd.DataFrame.query` could be faster with more rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

rdata={'first': {0: 'john', 1: 'david', 2: 'daniel', 3: 'john'}, 'last': {0: 'smith', 1: 'jones', 2: 'bond', 3: 'smith'}, 'ph': {0: 123456, 1: 456789, 2: 12345, 3: 234567}, 'address': {0: 'AB12 3CB', 1: 'EF45 6GH', 2: 'IJ78 9KL', 3: 'AB32 3CD'}, 'email': {0: 'js@js.com', 1: 'dj@dj.com', 2: 'db@db.com', 3: 'js@js.com'}, 'id': {0: 12345678, 1: 90123456, 2: 78901234, 3: 98765432}}
df = pd.DataFrame(rdata)

def func_loc(data):
    return data.loc[(data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john')]

def func_bool(data):
    return data[(data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john')]

def func_iloc(data):
    return data.iloc[np.where((data['last']=='smith') & (data['first']=='john'))]

def func_query(data):
    return data.query('last == "smith" and first == "john"')

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1_000, 3_000, 10_000, 30_000, 100_000],
    columns='func_loc func_bool func_iloc func_query'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df]*i)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

res.plot(loglog=True);
```

Output:

[image: image here]